# Property does not exists on type while using ngModel

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using `ngModel` to set the value of an HTML element.
How can I access a property of the desired object without getting a `Property does not exists on type` error?

Normally, instead of using `data.title` I would use `data['title']` or `(data as any).title`.
Both do not work with `[(ngModel)]` as they produce another error.

In addition to that I cannot use the safe/elvis operator although I need it.

My workaround is the following:
`[(ngModel)]="data && data.title"`

How do I solve both problems?

Edit:
`data` is an Object whose propertiers are being set after data is loaded asynchroniously from Firebase.
It is defined by `data:object = {};`
The property `title` exists after that.

Comment: Can you share the your complete code

Comment: add *ngIf="data != undefined" somewhere.

Comment: @j.Doe post component code related to `data`

Comment: you cannot bind 2 things with `ngModel`, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Call me stupid.

I found what I did wrong:

I used `data[title]` instead of `data['title']`

Answer (score -1):

You can use ngModel to set and get the value both.

HTML

```html
    <input [(ngModel)]="username">
    <button (click)="getValue()">Get Value</button>
```

TS

```js
    username: any;

    setValue() {
       this.username = "Deepika";
    }

    getValue() {
       console.log('username is -->', this.username)
    }
```